# Azure TFS deployment error "Invalid enum value 'FailedStartingRole' cannot be deserialized into type"

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-deployment

I tried to deploy from TFS, but receiving the error:

```
Exception Message: Invalid enum value 'FailedStartingRole' cannot be deserialized into type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Deployment.Workflow.AzureManagement.v1_7.InstanceStatus'. Ensure that the necessary enum values are present and are marked with EnumMemberAttribute attribute if the type has DataContractAttribute attribute. (type SerializationException)
Exception Stack Trace:    
   at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Any idea or similar encounter before?

Comment: Did you try to deploy from TFS to Azure or from VS-online to Azure? What did you try to deploy - Web Role or other?

Answer (score 3):

When I had the similar issue, I had a previously failed deployment in Azure. So to fix TFService error was just to delete a faulty deployment from Azure management portal.

Comment: This did it for me. Had a failed deployment, just needed to delete it and retry the build.

Comment: I, too, had a failed deployment that was causing a similar error. I wanted to keep it for tracking purposes, so I deployed once from Visual Studio, then subsequent deployments from Visual Studio Online succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

For a SerializationException type, check that a classes of WCF are attributed with a attribute DataContractAttribute  and there properties with DataMemberAttribute. Enums items need be attributed with an attribute EnumMemberAttribute.

I have some problems with Windows Azure 1.7, do you have another versions of Windows Azure installed?, verify that your are using WindowsAzure.Client. I you do an upgrade is posible then you have conflicts.

Comment: I tried to google for that exception but no luck. I am using SDK 2.0 locally