# Deploy fails - Invalid InstanceSize enum value for vmsize

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops

We have our code in a [Visual Studio Online](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/what-is-visual-studio-online-vs) TFS repository, 
and we build and deploy to Azure.  We have a [Build Definition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/build/build-your-apps-vs) using the Hosted Build Controller, and the `TfvcContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml`
build process template which is configured to deploy to our Windows Azure Deployment Environment.

Everything was working fine until we upgraded our Azure Cloud Service VM from **Small** to the [Standard_D1](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/22/new-d-series-virtual-machine-sizes/) size.
We made the appropriate change to the WebRole in our ServiceDefinition.csdef:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="PriceCalv3CS" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2014-06.2.4">
  <WebRole name="PriceCalv3CS.SPA" vmsize="Standard_D1">
    ...
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

And everything still works fine if we publish and deploy from our local Visual Studio 2013... but not from Visual Studio Online.

VSO compiles the solution successfully, but then throws this exception when trying to deploy:

```
Exception Message: Invalid enum value 'Standard_D1' cannot be deserialized into type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Deployment.Workflow.AzureManagement.v1_7.InstanceSize'. Ensure that the necessary enum values are present and are marked with EnumMemberAttribute attribute if the type has DataContractAttribute attribute. (type SerializationException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumDataContract.ReadEnumValue(String value, Int32 index, Int32 count)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumDataContract.ReadEnumValue(XmlReaderDelegator reader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   ...
```

It seems that VSO cannot handle the new(ish) instance size names that Azure now supports.
We are using [Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2013) - 2.5.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn873976.aspx), 
and tried upgrading to the latest 2.5.1, but that didn't help VSO.

The other references I've seen to this problem are in [social.msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/173d05da-f2c0-4b5b-a097-055cfb1b59c5/cd-build-fails-but-deployment-completes?forum=TFService) 
where there was a [bug opened](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1212246) that was closed with no resolution.

Someone with a [similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688386/azure-tfs-deployment-error) was able to resolve it by deleting their old builds, 
but that didn't work for me.  I tried creating a brand-new Build Definition, but that didn't help either.

It seems like we need to tell VSO to respect these new instance sizes.  But how?

---

MORE: I thought VSO was parsing the ServiceDefinition.csdef, and choking on `vmsize="Standard_D1"`, but that's not the case.  I changed it to `vmsize="Small"` and even `vmsize="broken"` and the error message still complains about "Invalid enum value 'Standard_D1'".

Answer (score 0):

If your previous instance was smaller than d1 then your deploy is in a datacenter that does not support D1.

If that is the case then you need to delete your current deployment, both vm and resource group. When you then do a new deploy as D1 your instance will end up in the correct data center.

Comment: We did that already.  And, as noted above, we are able to deploy successfully from VS on the desktop.  It's only from Visual Studio Online that we get the error.  So I don't think that's the problem.